# Multistore multi-store on separate hosting servers

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, cdn

I have an existing store with multiple storefronts for US,UK,Chinese versions.

Each storefront has a /en/, /uk/, /cn/.

Now we have a problem with the website showing in china, due to the firewall, it is very slow and often not loading at all. So we i am looking for a way to serve the Chinese market without compromising my US and europe markets.
the first option that comes to mind is using CDN, though i wonder if there is a proper service that serves both china and the rest of the world for a feasible fee.
The other option is to locally host the website in china, but then we compromise other markets.
The question is, if there is a way to split the hosting for each storefront, or have some kind on sync between 2 servers. So the chinese storefront will be hosted on a server in china, while the rest of the world will be served from a server in the US or some other place.
Our stock is very dynamic so updating separate installations manually is a big hassle.

Please advise

Answer (score 0):

yes, 
you will have to copy your code and database to china, and keep them in sync. 
configure DNS and magento store code to properly redirect and show correct store.
the only solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer...will that not cause my website to have duplicate content on search engines?
Will that not indicate for them that it is a clone of my website as it is served from different IP.

I want to make it as seamless as possible,  so the customer will not notice it is 2 different websites, not would google and buidu etc...

Comment: you dont have any duplicates, you just need to server `/cn/` on chinese server/DNS/IP

Comment: going to try that out, my only concern is for user and order data.
as store will be served based on geotargeting, so if a person opens an account in china and then flies to US, he will not be able to access his account nor see his orders etc.